# Can I stop Linux from listening to a USB input device as a keyboard, but still capture events with a program?

Tags: linux, debian, devices, events

I have a USB barcode scanner at `/dev/input/event0` (`/dev/input/by-id/usb-Metrologic_Metrologic_Scanner-event-kbd`), and scanning a barcode causes it to send keypress events. I'm capturing these keypresses using the [libdevinput](https://github.com/prullmann/libdevinput) Ruby library, which works great. The issue is that each barcode is also entered as a username, and subsequently a password on the Raspberry Pi, causing lots of failed login attempts. (The Raspberry Pi will be headless, and inside a microwave.)

How can I stop Linux from seeing the barcode scanner as an input device, and have my program be the sole event consumer? Or is there a different, better solution?

Comment: I do not recommend putting electronics in a microwave. Certainly not a running one.

Comment: That is definitely the most "wtf" part of this question.

Comment: Cheap Faraday cage?  Maybe there's a lot of RF in the area.

Comment: Hahaha, not IN the microwave. Everything sits behind the microwave's controller PCB, and I am not intending to cook my Raspberry Pi. I'm adding a barcode scanner for cooking instructions, as well as voice control and a redesigned touch pad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that I need to send an [EVIOCGRAB ioctl to the device, which grabs it for exclusive use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698686/304706).

Here's how to do it in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
BARCODE_SCANNER = "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Metrologic_Metrologic_Scanner-event-kbd"

require 'rubygems'
require 'libdevinput'
require 'ffi'
require 'ffi/tools/const_generator'

# We need access to the file
DevInput.class_eval { attr_reader :dev }

# Look up value of EVIOCGRAB constant
cg = FFI::ConstGenerator.new('input') do |gen|
  gen.include('linux/input.h')
  gen.const(:EVIOCGRAB, '%u', '(unsigned)')
end
EVIOCGRAB = cg['EVIOCGRAB'].to_i

scanner = DevInput.new(BARCODE_SCANNER)
# Send EVIOCGRAB to scanner, which grabs it for exclusive use by our process
scanner.dev.ioctl(EVIOCGRAB, 1)


puts "Waiting for events..."
scanner.each do |event|
  # Ignore everything except key press events
  next unless event.type == 1 && event.value == 1
  puts "Key: #{event.code_str}"
end
```

**Note**: You'll need to install the `libdevinput` gem, `ffi`, and Linux headers. If you are using a Linux version between `3.2.0` and `3.6.11`, you can replace the `FFI::ConstGenerator` part with `EVIOCGRAB = 1074021776`, and then you don't need `ffi` or Linux headers.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds somehow similar to [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64552/26952), so I'd try [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71029/26952) : if I understand correctly your problem, the barcode scanner should appear as a slave pointer of "Virtual core keyboard" when you do

```
xinput --list
```

Then maybe getting its ID and forcing it to float could help :

```
xinput float <id>
```

Comment: I think OP is seeing these on the console, not X. But in X this should work.

Comment: Ah, right.  Plus he has already found a solution…